# How to handle null values when writing to parquet from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Until recently `parquet` did not support `null` values - a questionable premise. In fact a recent version did finally add that support:

https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md

However it will be a long time before `spark` supports that new `parquet` feature - if ever. Here is the associated (`closed - will not fix`) JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10943

So what are folks doing with regards to null column values *today* when writing out `dataframe`'s to `parquet` ?   I can only think of *very* ugly horrible hacks like writing empty strings and .. well .. I have *no* idea what to do with numerical values to indicate `null` - short of putting some sentinel value in and having my code check for it (which is inconvenient and bug prone).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You misinterpreted [SPARK-10943](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10943). Spark does support writing `null` values to numeric columns.

The problem is that `null` alone carries no type information at all

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT null as comments").printSchema
root
 |-- comments: null (nullable = true)
```

As per [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10943?focusedCommentId=14959304&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14959304) by [Michael Armbrust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3161893/michael-armbrust) all you have to do is cast:

```
scala> spark.sql("""SELECT CAST(null as DOUBLE) AS comments""").printSchema
root
|-- comments: double (nullable = true)
```

and the result can be safely written to Parquet.

Comment: If you're using sql something like this works: create table my_table as select distinct colx, coly, cast(null as string) colz from foo where lower(bar) like '%bat%'

Comment: Is it possible to somehow cast fields of a StructType? I mean, there is a column which type is a struct which has a field which type is inferred as NullType. Is it possible to cast it as well?

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a PySpark solution for this (`df` is a dataframe with columns of `NullType`):

```py
# get dataframe schema
my_schema = list(df.schema)

null_cols = []

# iterate over schema list to filter for NullType columns
for st in my_schema:
    if str(st.dataType) == 'NullType':
        null_cols.append(st)

# cast null type columns to string (or whatever you'd like)
for ncol in null_cols:
    mycolname = str(ncol.name)
    df = df \
        .withColumn(mycolname, df[mycolname].cast('string'))
```

Comment: This solution can be extended to handle nested NullType columns buy changing the line to `if 'NullType' in str(st.dataType):`

Comment: What if the NullType columns are null arrays?